# Is there any other use of <link> tag?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Is there any other use of  tag? which is useful or it's only for to link css and favicon.?

and what is the difference between `<a href=#>` and `<link>`? is link only can be placed in `<head>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are all *sorts* of uses for `link`. [Here's a list](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/interactive-elements.html#linkTypes) from the HTML5 specification. Link to alternate versions of the page, an icon for the page, the first/next/previous/last page of a series (if it's a series), ...

Comment: +1 I haven't use other than to link css and favicon. will see for other usage.

Comment: do u know any example of series?

Comment: @Jitendra: Examples using the link tag, no, but then I don't do a lot of "view source". :-) But a series would be (for instance) an article that is divided into pages (like PCMag, Tom's Hardware, etc. does with their reviews, to maximize ad rotation and avoid any individual page being too big). The first page would have a `link rel="next"` referencing page 2, etc. Slideshows might do the same thing. A blog post could be considered part of a series. You get the idea.

Comment: @Jitendra: Tom's Hardware doesn't seem to use the series feature, but apparently they use `stylesheet`, `alternate` (referencing their RSS feed), and `search`: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/Monitors-Displays,review-29797.html